# How to perform s segue in this custom disclosure button?

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue

I am a new bee in IOS development, I found JPSThumbnailAnnotation in github, which really inspired me.
https://github.com/jpsim/JPSThumbnailAnnotation

My question is how to perform a segue in this custom disclosure button?
`[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"XXX" sender:self];`

 can not be preformed in 
 `- (void)didTapDisclosureButton`

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, since you have not specified what `- (void)didTapDisclosureButton` is, there you go.
On the page you linked to, I found this example

```
  JPSThumbnail *thumbnail = [[JPSThumbnail alloc] init];
thumbnail.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"empire.jpg"];
thumbnail.title = @"Empire State Building";
thumbnail.subtitle = @"NYC Landmark";
thumbnail.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(40.75f, -73.99f);
thumbnail.disclosureBlock = ^{ NSLog(@"selected Empire"); };

[mapView addAnnotation:[JPSThumbnailAnnotation annotationWithThumbnail:thumbnail]];
```

So why not:

```
thumbnail.disclosureBlock = ^{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"XXX" sender:self];
};
```

As specified on that same page

> You can also set a block to be run when the disclosure button is tapped.